# Error while using URL Launcher in Flutter

Tags: android, flutter, url-launcher

```
onTap: () async {
  final url = products[index].url;

  if (!await canLaunch(url)) {
    await launch(url);
  } else {
    throw 'Could not launch $url';
  }
```

Error :

```
I/UrlLauncher(20613): component name for https://www.crucial.in/products/memory/desktop-dram is {com.android.chrome/com.google.android.apps.chrome.IntentDispatcher}
E/flutter (20613): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(209)] Unhandled Exception: Could not launch https://www.crucial.in/products/memory/desktop-dram
E/flutter (20613): #0      HomeScreen.build.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure>
package:crucial/screens/home_screen.dart:52
E/flutter (20613): <asynchronous suspension>
```

Comment: Probably because you have incorrect code logic? Try change `if (!await canLaunch(url))` to `if (await canLaunch(url))`

Answer (score 1):

Add this to your android manifest file:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.QUERY_ALL_PACKAGES"/>
```

And use this:

```
Future<void>_launchURL(String link) async {
  if (await canLaunchUrl(Uri.parse(link))) {
    await launchUrl(Uri.parse(link));
  } else {
    throw 'Could not launch $link';
  }
}
```

Works for me